# Selectize Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, selectize.js

I am trying to pass custom data attributes to my selectize component. Below is the static HTML generated which I wish to selectize:

```
<select id="colour-filter" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0">
   <option value="" data-data="false" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.$blank"></option>
   <option value="2" data-data="#FFFFFF" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$2">White</option>
   <option value="1" data-data="#FF0000" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$1">Red</option>
   <option value="3" data-data="#C0C0C0" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$3">Silver</option>
   <option value="4" data-data="#808080" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$4">Gray</option>
   <option value="5" data-data="#800000" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$5">Maroon</option>
   <option value="0" data-data="false" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.$showAll">All colours</option>
</select>
```

But, I am getting the following error, when this piece of code (`JSON.parse("#FFFFFF")`) is executed inside selectize:

> VM11923:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position
>   0

Even if I remove the # from the data attribute, it doesn't work.
Why is selectize not able to generate the data JSON for this html? How do I work around instead?

This is jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/gutzmnsw/

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gutzmnsw/

Comment: @YOU would you mind elaborating?

Comment: selectize.js and jquery is all I need for this, although I have included both in the fiddle but in fiddle it is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked well with the following HTML, though I wonder why do I have to send the JSON and sending just the attribute value for data-data won't work, and there is no mention in the documentation about this:

```
<select id="colour-filter" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0">
   <option value="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.$blank"></option>
   <option value="2" data-data="{&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#FFFFFF&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$2">White</option>
   <option value="1" data-data="{&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#FF0000&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$1">Red</option>
   <option value="3" data-data="{&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#C0C0C0&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$3">Silver</option>
   <option value="4" data-data="{&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#808080&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$4">Gray</option>
   <option value="5" data-data="{&quot;hex&quot;:&quot;#800000&quot;}" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.1:$5">Maroon</option>
   <option value="0" data-reactid=".0.1.0.2.0.0.1.0.$showAll">All colours</option>
</select>
```

Selectized my component this way:

```
$('#colour-filter').selectize({
  plugins: ['restore_on_backspace'],
  persist: false,
  allowEmptyOption: true,
  selectOnTab: true,
  render: {
    option: (item, escape)->
      if item.hex && item.hex == "#FFFFFF"
        option_html = '<div>' + '<div style="background-color: ' + item.hex + ';border: 1px solid black"></div><span>' +
          escape(item.text) + '</span>' + '</div>';
      else if item.hex
        option_html = '<div>' + '<div style="background-color: ' + item.hex + '"></div><span>' +
            escape(item.text) + '</span>' + '</div>';
      else
        option_html = '<div>' + escape(item.text) + '</div>';
      return option_html
  },
```